# Keeping parallel arrays updated when adding a new element in order

Tags: c++, c, arrays, algorithm, parallel-processing

This is a college assignment so I would prefer pseudo code, or just a basic idea of the process; however, any help would be appreciated.

The problem:

I have two parallel arrays: array **courseNames** and array **maximumEnrollment**.
I must use a function provided by faculty that inserts new elements into array **courseNames** by alphabetical order:

```
// Assume the elements of the array are already in order
// Find the position where value could be added to keep
//    everything in order, and insert it there.
// Return the position where it was inserted
//  - Assumes that we have a separate integer (size) indicating how
//     many elements are in the array
//  - and that the "true" size of the array is at least one larger 
//      than the current value of that counter

template <typename T>
int addInOrder (T* array, int& size, T value)
{
  // Make room for the insertion
  int toBeMoved = size - 1;
  while (toBeMoved >= 0 && value < array[toBeMoved]) {
    array[toBeMoved+1] = array[toBeMoved];
    --toBeMoved;
  }
  // Insert the new value
  array[toBeMoved+1] = value;
  ++size;
  return toBeMoved+1;
}
```

Since the array **courseNames** is empty, I don't have to worry about the array being in order when I first use the function. 
All the input comes from a file separated by lines, every line contains the name of the class(ei. CS150) and the maximum enrollment allowed(ei. 50). 
The first array, holds the names of the courses, while the second array holds the maximum enrollment.

My code for the function that reads the inputs from the files looks like this:

```
/*
 * Read the course names and max enrollments. Keep the courses
 * in alphabetic order by course name.
 */
void readCourses (istream& courseFile, int numCourses,
          string* courseNames, int* maxEnrollments)
{
  //!! Insert your code here
    for(int i =0; i < numCourses; ++i){
        string course;
        courseFile >> course;
        int pos = addInOrder(courseNames, numCourses, course);
        courseFile >> maxEnrollments[pos];
    }
}
```

I'm using the position given to the elements of **courseNames** as the index to store the maximum enrollment for the given course. The problem arises when a new value is inserted into **courseNames** and I get the position in which it was added. If I use that position, the old value of the index will be overwritten and everything will fall out of place.

My **question** is, how can I prevent this from happening? How can I find out what value was replaced to keep the array in order and make the parallel array *maximumEnrollment** match the index of **courseNames** for each course?

Thank you in advance for any help you might be able to provide!

**UPDATE**

I was also provided this function:

```
// Add value into array[index], shifting all elements already in positions
//    index..size-1 up one, to make room.
//  - Assumes that we have a separate integer (size) indicating how
//     many elements are in the array
//  - and that the "true" size of the array is at least one larger 
//      than the current value of that counter

template <typename T>
void addElement (T* array, int& size, int index, T value)
{
  // Make room for the insertion
  int toBeMoved = size - 1;
  while (toBeMoved >= index) {
    array[toBeMoved+1] = array[toBeMoved];
    --toBeMoved;
  }
  // Insert the new value
  array[index] = value;
  ++size;
}
```

So I changed my code to this:

```
/*
 * Read the course names and max enrollments. Keep the courses
 * in alphabetic order by course name.
 */
void readCourses (istream& courseFile, int numCourses,
          string* courseNames, int* maxEnrollments)
{
  //!! Insert your code here
    int size = 1;
    for(int i =0; i < numCourses; i++){
        string course;
        int maxEnroll;
        courseFile >> course;
        courseFile >> maxEnroll;

        int pos = addInOrder(courseNames, size, course);
        addElement(maxEnrollments, size, pos, maxEnroll);

    }
}
```

Comment: You're passing the wrong size variable to your addInOrder function. You should be passing the current size of courseNames. Before your for loop, you should have something like "int size = 0" and pass that in your function.  The way you have it, it should be an infinite loop.  I'm guessing the bounds of courseNames and maxEnrollments have already been set in a separate function?

Comment: Thanks man, that's something I was definitely missing. But also, how can I know what element moved in the first array, so that the value that belongs to it in the second array can obtain the same index?

Comment: @JonathanChandler I haven't figured it out yet, but  think you've put me on the right path. Thanks man, I've been working on this for three days. I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: So you have to return two arrays?  If not, I would use one array with pair<string, int>.  If you do have to use two arrays, you could make a separate function that shifts your other array forward from pos.  It would work similarly to their addInOrder function, except you already know where to end.

Comment: @JonathanChandler So basically  I would jut have to shift all the values of maximumEnrollment once to the right at pos, and insert the new max value at pos?

Comment: I think I got it! At least it looks like it, can't compile because I'm missing some other functions but will update the answer and let me know if you think that does it. @JonathanChandler